# create a list of list of parameters from a file

Tags: python, list, file

Hi i am trying to create a list of parameters from a file

The final result should be something like

param=[[field],[units],[height],[site]]

The problem is that the information is split into lines and some of the parameters do not have all the information

```
#info in the file
[field1]
unit=m/s
height=70.4
site=site1
[field2]
height=20.6
site=site2
[field3]
units=m
...
```

so i would like to fulfill all the fields in such a way that, if there is not information assigns 0 or ''

Final result in the example

param={field1:'m/s',70.4,'site1',field2:'',20.6,site2, field3:'m',0,''}

I know how to create a dictionary from list of lists but not to set default values ('' for the strings values an 0 for the numeric ones) in case some values are missing

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [**`ConfigParser`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) will help.

Comment: So they don't all have the same numbers of fields?

Comment: Each field may have units,height,site. In fact i should create a dictionary with {field:[unit,height,site]}

Answer (score 1):

You could group using a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open("test.txt") as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for line in map(str.rstrip, f):
        if line.startswith("["):
            d["fields"].append(line.strip("[]"))
        else:
            k,v = line.split("=")
            d[k].append(v)
```

Input::

```
[field1]
unit=m/s
height=70.4
site=site1
[field2]
height=20.6
site=site2
[field3]
unit=m
height=6.0
site=site3
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'fields': ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], 
'site': ['site1', 'site2', 'site3'], 'unit': ['m/s', 'm'],
 'height': ['70.4', '20.6', '6.0']})
```

If you actually want to group by field, you can use `itertools.groupby` grouping on lines that start with `[`:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("test.txt") as f:
    grps, d = groupby(map(str.rstrip,f), key=lambda x: x.startswith("[")), {}
    for k,v in grps:
        if k:
            k, v = next(v).strip("[]"), list(next(grps)[1])
            d[k] = v
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'field2': ['height=20.6', 'site=site2'], 
'field3': ['unit=m', 'height=6.0', 'site=site3'],
 'field1': ['unit=m/s', 'height=70.4', 'site=site1']}
```

Each `k` is a line  starting with `[`, we then call next on the grouper object to get all the lines up to the next line starting with `[` or the EOF:

Answer (score 1):

This would fill in the missing information.

```
f= open('file.txt','r')     
field, units, height, site =  [],[],[],[]
param = [ field, units, height, site]

lines = f.readlines()

i=0
while True:
    try:
        line1 = lines[i].rstrip()
        if line1.startswith('['):
            field.append(line1.strip('[]'))
        else:
            field.append(0)
            i-= 1
    except:
        field.append(0)    

    try:
        line2 = lines[i+1].rstrip()
        if line2.startswith('unit') or line2.startswith('units'):
            units.append(line2.split('=')[-1])
        else:
            units.append('')
            i-=1
    except:
        units.append('')

    try:
        line3 = lines[i+2].rstrip()
        if line3.startswith('height'):
            height.append(line3.split('=')[-1])
        else:
            height.append(0)
            i-=1
    except:
        height.append(0)    

    try:
        line4 = lines[i+3].rstrip()
        if line4.startswith('site'):
            site.append(line4.split('=')[-1])
        else:
            site.append('')                       
    except:
        site.append('')
        break

    i +=4
```

Output:

```
param: 
[['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
 ['m/s', '', 'm'],
 ['70.4', '20.6', 0],
 ['site1', 'site2', '']]
```